# Will downloading on one PC on my home LAN affect network performance of another PC in the LAN that is streaming from within the LAN

Tags: networking, lan, video-streaming

I am downloading from the internet on one pc, mainly torrents. I am streaming video on another pc from a NAS. All device are connected to the same router. Will the downloading be affecting the speed of the streaming?

Answer (score 1):

This depends mostly on how they're connected.  If they're connected over wireless and they're all using the same band (ie. 2.5GHz or 5GHz) then the downloading/torrents could slow other clients down because of the congestion in the wireless spectrum.

If they're hard wired or if the downloading system is a separate band from the streaming system (ie. downloading on 2.5GHz and the streaming on 5GHz) then it's not so much of an issue.

Unless of course your router/access point has some firmware bug causing it to have problems handling the high volume of connections from the torrents... in which case it could be doing any number of things.

Comment: Thank you. The device downloading is connectedcvia wifi and the other device is cabled in via homeplug

Answer (score 0):

It will probably have a minimal impact. The bottleneck will be the internet connection though not usually the local lan. The quality of the router may also impacts performance if this is the device acting as a switch for your network and not just routing

Comment: Yes it is acting a switch - it is the router that was provided by the isp